# JavaScript getters/setters and extending objects

Tags: javascript, extend, setter, getter

I'm researching getters and setters in JavaScript and how well they go with spread functions for extending objects, like jQuery's $.extend and Underscore's _.extend. The code setup is as follows:

```
var test = {
    get size() { return this._size; },
    set size(val) { this._size = val; },
}   

test.size = "LARGE";
console.log(test.size);

//$.extend(test, { get size() { return "MEDIUM"; } });
_.extend(test, { get size() { return "MEDIUM"; } });

console.log(test.size);
test.size = "SMALL";
console.log(test.size);
```

In Chrome and Firefox I get:

```
LARGE
MEDIUM
SMALL
```

Can someone explain me what's happening there? Why after call the original setter, the original getter is also restored?

Comment: I think that the getter replaces both the original setter and getter, and that at the end it just sets the property `size` to "SMALL". Do `console.log(this._size);` at the end and see what you get..

Comment: @JCOC611 - I don't think so. See my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Underscore's `extend` looks like this:

```
 _.extend = function(obj) {
   each(slice.call(arguments, 1), function(source) {
     for (var prop in source) obj[prop] = source[prop];
   });
   return obj;
 };
```

It iterates the source object's properties, adds them to the target object, and then returns the target object. When it copies the `size` property to the object you're extending, it basically does this:

```
obj['size'] = source['size']
```

That is, it uses the new object's getter, but copies only the value returned by that getter. It doesn't transfer the getter itself.

To further demonstrate this, try the following:

```
var test = {
    get size() { return this._size; },
    set size(val) { this._size = val; },
}   

for (var p in test) {
    console.log(p)
}
```

Which outputs only:

```
size
```

(It doesn't iterate the getters or setters.)

Comment: How would I go about writing an extend method that DOES copy over getters / setters?